# Is it possible to (conditionally) lookup from two different collections

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

Let's suppose I have 3 schemas:
1. User:

```
const User = mongoose.model('users', {
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true
    }
}
```

2. SuperUser:

```
const SuperUser= mongoose.model('superusers', {
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true
    }
}
```

3. Messages:

```
const Message = mongoose.model('Message', {
    content: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true
    },
    sender: {
        type: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.String,
            required: true,
            enum : ['USER,'SUPER_USER'],
        },
        id: {
            type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
            required: true
        }
    }
})
```

I want to use the aggregation framework, to fetch (all) messages, and at the same time populate the nested sender object, inside the message with the data from the tables 'superusers' or 'users' (The columns of superusers and users are just an example).
Is it possible to 'conditionally lookup', meaning to lookup either the superusers or users, based on the type? I'm very new to the aggregate framework, so this may be an obvious solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is quite possible with mongoose what you are trying to achieve. You can use  `refPath` while defining the schema. And your `enum` should be the collection names i.e. `User`, `SuperUser`, and not the capital case.

```
const Message = mongoose.model('Message', {
    content: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true
    },
    sender: {
        type: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.String,
            required: true,
            enum : ['User','SuperUser'],
        },
        id: {
            type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
            required: true,
            refPath : "sender.type"
        }
    }
})
```

and then you can populate the documents like this:

```
Message.find({}).populate("sender.id");
```

Your sender will be available in `sender.id`

**To simplify**, you can simply store sender `id` in `sender` field, and store `senderType` separately, so that you don't have to use `sender.id` for the sender document, and its much **cleaner**.

```
const Message = mongoose.model('Message', {
    content: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true
    },
    sender: {
        type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
        required: true,
        refPath : "senderType"
    },
    senderType: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.String,
        required: true,
        enum : ['User,'SuperUser'],
    }
})
```

And now you can populate the documents like this:

```
Message.find({}).populate("sender");
```

Your sender document/object will be available in `sender` field

For detailed information, read [Mongoose documentation on dynamic-ref](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#dynamic-ref)

Comment: I have the same use case for refPath. It does not work on my side.